# Почему Не видит ANDROID SDK, как исправить ошибку?

Tags: android, android-studio

Emulator: PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows]!

ANDROID SDK установлено

Comment: `C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows` - он там есть  Android SDK?

Comment: да. Все файлы так же. Я проверял

Answer (score 1):

Если ваше имя пользователя в Windows содержит кириллицу, попробуйте его переименовать, используя только латинские символы в соответствии с данной инструкцией https://superuser.com/questions/890812/how-to-rename-the-user-folder-in-windows-10. Для меня это решило проблему запуска эмулятора.